# Не отображается фон в Mozilla

Tags: html, html5, img, сss3

Делаю фон через css

```
.header_big_f {
    height: 456px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: url(/web/img/fon.png) no-repeat center bottom;
}
```

Вот оно в html так вызывается.

```
<div class="header_big_f">

</div>
```

Во всех браузерах работает отлично(GC,IE,ME,Opera). А вот мозила не грузит картинку. Почему так. При запуске в мозиле, навожу на стиль и там пишет. Не удалоь загрузить картинку.. В чем проблема?

Comment: Может быть мозила требует в кавычках писать путь до картинки? А ширину почему не указываете?

Comment: ширина авто, то есть та какая у картинки.
в кавычках так же.

Comment: ширина авто, то есть та какая у картинки - не сработает, да и с какой радости должно работать? Вебкит просто по умолчанию блок на всю ширину растягивает, а Мозила скатывается непонятно куда который год(( Ну ладно, это лирика. Задайте width:100%; или сколько там нужно, бэкгранд никак не передает ширину изображения в нем.